# qmake cannot locate any source or header files

Tags: qt, qt5, qmake

I am trying to bring my project from one computer with `qt4` to another where I freshly installed `qt5` and I am having a very strange problem.

**The qmake suddenly cannot find any of my source or header files.**

Here is a minimalist example:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/Dir/
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/Dir/

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    f.h \

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

Where `Dir/f.h` exists in the same directory as `untitled.pro`. And I get this output from qmake:

```
05:18:45: Starting: "/opt/QtSDK/5.0.2/gcc/bin/qmake" 
/home/martin/Projects/untitled/untitled.pro 
-r -spec linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=declarative_debug CONFIG+=qml_debug
WARNING: Failure to find: f.h
05:18:45: The process "/opt/QtSDK/5.0.2/gcc/bin/qmake" exited normally.
```

I have absolutely no idea what is causing this. What could be the problem?

EDIT:

When I manually prepend the name like this:

```
HEADERS += Dir/f.h \
```

`qmake` doesn't complain.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't understand.  =).  If f.h is in the folder Dir then you need to add the full path to that file.  Which is why HEADERS += Dir/f.h works.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Huytard but I did not need to do this before. I would just add the directory: DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/Dir/ and then I do not need to write the full paths. Why is this suddenly a problem is making me mad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Same issue solved when I include VPATH in pro file

Eg:
VPATH += ../../libraries/
INCLUDE += ../../libraries/

Also with qt 5 we need not to include DEPENDPATH in pro files

Answer (score 4):

You never defined PWD. The double-dollar sign '$$' prefix indicates a qmake variable defined earlier in the pro file. In your case, the `$$PWD` portion is completely unnecessary. If you remove it entirely, everything should compile just fine.

Edit: Additionally, [they quietly changed `DEPENDPATH` behavior in Qt 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769541/does-a-qt-5-programmer-have-to-know-about-dependpath-qmake-variable). As of Qt 5, `qmake` now defaults to using your `INCLUDEPATH`s when looking for the `SOURCES` and `HEADERS` (`config += depend_includepath`). Simply drop the `DEPENDPATH` line and you should be good.

```
INCLUDEPATH += "Dir"
```

Reference: [Qmake variables in .pro files](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/22890-Qmake-variable)

Comment: Thank you, but the result is the same.

Comment: Does removing the extra \ after `f.h` fix it?

Comment: Nevermind. Try removing the DEPENDPATH line altogether and read this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769541/does-a-qt-5-programmer-have-to-know-about-dependpath-qmake-variable

Comment: INCLUDEPATH has nothing to do with finding files for SOURCES/HEADERS, but with resolving includes at compile time. HEADERS += Dir/f.h is the way to go. That DEPENDPATH thing was probably an unintended side-effect in Qt4.